# Wipe secure USB drive showing up as 2 devices

Tags: usb-flash-drive, wipe

I have a 16GB USB flash drive that has been set up by a program, memup/memorybar, to be separated into a public and a private part. I am not the one who set it up, so I do not know the password, and i only want to wipe the entire thing and reuse it as a normal 16GB USB drive. It is, however, not showing as one device with partitions, but as a flash drive (160MB, the public part) and as a CD drive (6MB, read-only, contains software/manuals for the drive).
The drive is from "memup", and the pdf contains a link http://www.memup.com, that is however dead, so i guess the company doesn't exist anymore?
Both gparted and fdisk only see the two devices, no partitions, however lsusb tells me that there is a flash drive from "Silicon Motion, Inc."; their website doesn't provide any information on a secure USB drive either, or any hint that it might even have to do anything with the hidden drive/partition.

I am unable to recover the password, the internet did not provide any information and there is no company to ask for support any more.
Is there now any way for me to wipe that flash drive and access/remove the hidden drive/partition and make it one 16GB drive again?

Comment: So you set a password then forgot it?  I am not sure I understand the question?  Was it 16GB at any point in time?

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough, it should be better now